# My account is no longer linked

Tags: support, openid

Hi, I was on stackoverflow yesterday and was doing well. Today all of the sudden when I visited the site, it didn't log me in automatically. Ok fine, so I clicked on login, chose my openid account provider (google) and it says to confirm new account creation. Why? did I just lose all the progress I made, which isn't much, but still.

Please help.

Comment: This account? http://stackoverflow.com/users/286618/rolyrolls

Comment: yes. that is my account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have multiple gmail accounts.

Log out of gmail or use a different web browser.

Comment: Nevermind...the second account I tried asked me to allow access. So I figured it wasn't the account I use for SO and backed out. I tried it now and it works. So sorry for wasting time.

Comment: I actually went ahead and assciated both gmail accounts to the same SO account and META SO account just in case.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mail team@stackoverflow.com and explain your problem.

---

<sup>It is possible that something is up with OpenID this morning; I arrived at work to find my SO and meta accounts had logged themselves out, and I could not log in using my Livejournal account (this happened once before, a few weeks ago).</sup>

If there is a persistent issue, an announcement will be made here on meta and on the blog.*

*<sub>And if there isn't, we will whip Jeff until he makes such a post.</sub>

Comment: Is your post getting smaller every time this page has a new action?

Comment: @random: It's the incredible shrinking post!